# What are the strengths, weaknesses and/or recommendations for a BLB Mosquito Saddle?

Tags: road-bike, product-rec, saddle

I ask this here because I couldn't find too much information or reviews about BLB Mosquito saddles. If administrators find this question doesn't fit into this place, please feel free to remove/edit this question.

---

So I'm about to order a 'Tan' version of a BLB Mosquito saddle (from London to Bogota, that saddle will travel too much far I've traveled in my entire life). I fell in love with it because its style and color (it suits perfectly with my bike, a somewhat customized GIOS Torino Pro '86); since having a BLB handlebar, I feel BLB is doing a very nice work with their products. I have to say I felt somewhat tempted to get a Brooks saddle because of their reputation thing, but I didn't liked any of them (too much fancy for me, and they're very expensive) so I decided to get the BLB one (it happens to be inspired by Brooks saddles).

[image: Brick Lane Bikes Mosquito Saddle, Tan]

Along with it, I'm ordering a Velo Orange long setback seatpost. I guess I won't have any problems using that BLB Mosquito saddle with that seatpost, but just in case I ask here if someone have had any experience with that seatpost.

Getting to the point: since I commute about 2 hours/day (40 km/day, 200 km/week) and I'm riding with a old, cheap, wider and doesn't-even-have-foam-inside saddle, do you think it's a good choice going for the BLB one? Do you have any recommendations for its usage or keeping its leather in good look? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a leather saddle? The thing to remember with leather is that, just like shoes, it will mould (somewhat) to your shape during the breaking-in process. So, you should expect some short-term pain (breaking in) for some long-term gain (a well-fitting saddle). My advice would be to get the breaking in done and dusted before you go on your trip.

Comment: @PeteH yes, it's a leather saddle. Wonder if it's really made of good leather, or "good" leather...
Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the BLB Mosquito it is marketed as a "race" saddle which in the world of leather saddles seems to be short hand for narrow with the expectation that your cockpit setup has lots of handle bar drop (handle bars below saddle). Depending on the width of your sit bones, these saddles can be uncomfortable in a more upright position, as I have learned.

#### BLB Mosquito Race - side view

[image: BLB Mosquito Race]

#### Brooks B15 Swallow

The BBL Mosquito also looks remarkably similar the [Brooks B15 Swallow saddle](http://www.brooksengland.com/catalogue-and-shop/saddles/road+%26+mtb/B15+Swallow+Chrome/).

[image: Brooks B15]

As an owner of a B15 I can must advise you to carefully consider this saddle decision as it is really designed for race bikes. I am relatively average in stature and on the lighter side for weight.  I found this type of saddle was only comfortable in a racing position (i.e., 5-10 cm of drop on the handle bars).  Anything higher and my pelvis would rotate enough that the my sit bones would strike the metal rails.

Now everyone's anatomy is different, including sit bone width.  But for more general applications and for a more diverse array of body types, I think you should consider a wider saddle such as a Brooks B17.  Either that or measure the width of the BLB and compare it to the Brooks B17 to ensure the saddle is a bit wider.

As far as build quality, I haven't the foggiest about BLB!

### Leather Saddle Caveat

Most seem to be drawn to leather saddles for their looks. I am so-so on the looks, and a much bigger proponent on the comfort, once you choose a model that is appropriate to the application.  This is where all the marketing speak has let us down.  The descriptions on  how the saddles can be expected to fit is basically non-existing.  This is unfortunate as the saddles can be quite uncomfortable for some application/body type combinations due to the fact the saddles work as a hammock and use a solid rail.

This is where modern saddles can be better as they can be expected to provide adequate comfort to a larger array of body sizes due to the use of padding. That said, once you get the kinks worked out, in 15+ years of competition and 20+ years of cycling, I have never found a more comfortable solution.

Comment: Thanks for your gently response! Since I'm commuting on a good ol' road bike as I wrote, I think this BLB saddle would be a good choice. However, you (and @Chris in AK) made me wonder if there could be another good option before going to that (since here in Bogota rains a lot and maybe a leather saddle could be ruined in a short time). Thanks!

Comment: @acidrums4 - Bogata has a yearly rainfall of 824 mm.  I have used a leather saddle for years in areas that have annual rain falls of 1500-2500mm without any issues.  Just profide the leather and don't leave it out in the rain uncovered.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything specifically about this model saddle, but all leather saddles share the same group of strengths and weaknesses.

Leather Saddles have a few drawbacks.  They require a break in period.  They require regular maintenance, more so when used in foul weather.  They tend to be heavier than most current saddle designs.  There are mixed reviews on their durability in below freezing weather.  They have advantages as well.  Eventually, when cared for properly, they will essentially become a custom saddle fitted to you.  They can be cooler than many modern designs when used in warm weather.

The long and short is that they require MUCH more maintenance then other current saddle options which are essentially install and forget for potentially more comfort.

My recommendation is that if you like the "look" of a leather saddle, they may not be for you.  If you are aiming for the most comfortable saddle possible and willing to sacrifice some amount of time doing maintenance, they may be for you.

Comment: Maintenance of leather saddles is not THAT hard, a half a minute at best to add some profide and check the tension. The comfort however can be amazing! I have never had a "modern" saddle fit as comfortably.

Comment: True.  Especially if you are used to it.  However, if you ride in cold dry conditions (like I do), the frequency of that increases.  My sit bones are apparently not as sensitive as some peoples, because I haven't ever had comfort issues with current saddle stock.  The extra effort would not be worth it in my case.

Comment: Good point about temperature. Alaska can be bloody cold! I have never personally ridden a leather saddle in temperatures below -10 C. I could see leather being a liability in very cold environments.